# Persp-mode doesn't recover last activated perspective and doesn't restore all buffers

Tags: persp-mode

I'm using [persp-mode](https://github.com/Bad-ptr/persp-mode.el/).

```el
(setq-default use-package-always-defer t)

(use-package persp-mode
  :init
  (setq-default
   persp-auto-resume-time 0.1
   persp-keymap-prefix (kbd "C-c C-w"))
  (persp-mode 1)
  :config
  (setq-default
   persp-auto-save-fname ".persp"
   persp-auto-save-num-of-backups 0
   persp-autokill-buffer-on-remove nil
   persp-save-dir user-emacs-directory))
```

Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Start Emacs, create a `dotemacs` perspective with `persp-copy`.
2. Visit `dotemacs.org`, it is added to the perspective.
3. Visit then Magit buffer for that file, it is not added to the perspective.
4. Add that Magit buffer with `(persp-add-buffer (current-buffer))`.
5. Save `.persp` with `(persp-save-state-to-file persp-auto-save-fname))`. https://bpaste.net/show/3c3ebf87da29

When I restart Emacs:

- Persp doesn't restore `dotemacs` perspective, perhaps intended but I haven't found a way in the customization menus.
- The Magit buffer is saved in the `.persp` file, but is not open, nor restored.

My questions:

- How do I mark "active" a perspective to restore to on startup?
- How do I make Magit buffers automatically added to my perspectives?
- What are "leaves" in the `.persp` file?
- What are "weak" perspectives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the lack of support for this package, I'm now using `desktop` and [`eyebrowse`](https://github.com/wasamasa/eyebrowse) which I think is a better alternative.

Here is my configuration for the 2: https://github.com/angrybacon/dotemacs/blob/master/dotemacs.org#23-windows.